# Why isn't if else faster than using a default value?

Tags: javascript, performance

If we have two ways of assigning this variable, either

```
if(condition){
  var a = "Condition is true";
} else {
  var a = "Condition is false";
}
```

or

```
var a = "Condition is false";
if(condition){
  a = "Condition is true";
}
```

I personally would have expected the former to be way faster, considering the variable is always only written once as opposed to possibly being written to twice, and the condition is used in both cases.

Since Javascript is the language I am the most fluent in, have created [this jsperf](http://jsperf.com/else-vs-defaule-value), and it seems that both variants are roughly equally fast. Why is that?

- Is the cost of writing to a variable that small?
- Is optimization going on which makes both cases equal? (In the case of Firefox, it seems both cases **are** equal!)

If you have an explanation for this behavior, examples of other languages which contradict this one or maybe my jsperf is simply faulty, I would be really interested in that.

Comment: both strings have to be embedded in the code, regardless, so technically, it's simply a pointer assignment internally. `mov eax, [location_of_string]`. that's a 1 cycle operation and in the grand scheme of things, essentially "free".  doing two assignments may have "double" the cost, but the cost is so microscopic it's pretty much unmeasurable.

Comment: @Marc Is the entire test case not very small so that even this small difference should be more visible?

Answer (score 2):

Let's put everything that might take any amount of time unrelated to this test in the setup:

```
condition = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
a = undefined;
trueval = "Condition is true";
falseval = "Condition is false";
```

Now our cases are:

```
//------------------------
//Using else
if(condition){
  a = trueval;
} else {
  a = falseval;
}
//------------------------
//Using a default value
a = falseval;
if(condition){
  a = trueval;
}
//------------------------
//Extra case for curiosity, using ?:
a = condition ? trueval : falseval;
//------------------------
```

And [here are the results](http://jsperf.com/else-vs-defaule-value/3). In this case, if/else is equivalent with ?:, and the two-assignment approach is indeed noticeably slower **given that this is the only thing you're doing**. Note also this is the result for Chrome and other browsers might differ:

```
Using else:            42,623,032
Using a default value: 35,654,982
Using ?::              42,206,645
```

It's probably not going to affect much in real code - indeed, even just the overhead of processing a string in the other test made the difference almost insignificant.

Comment: I see! However, it seems in Firefox the result is reversed. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: Another question i have is: In my version, why are both strings processed regardless of whether they are used?

Comment: @JustAPoring: I'm not entirely sure... I don't know enough about its internals to say. I've asked on the #jsapi IRC chat, will see if they reply. About the strings, I'm not sure whether both are processed, but at least one is going to be..

Comment: Thanks! Regarding the strings, I was thinking that if they werent, my code would show even bigger differences since you mentioned the string processing was the heavy part here...

Answer (score 1):

Please get rid of randomizing in the benchmark: how on earth do you know if all the math randoms gave true or false? It is **extremely unlikely*** that 100 samples give 50 trues and falses.

Try this: http://jsperf.com/else-vs-defaule-value/5

*For example simulate 100 samples with 100 benchmark runs:

```
var totals = new Array(100)
var a = new Array(100)

for (var j = 0; j < 100; ++j) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        a[i] = !! Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    }
    totals[j] = a.filter(Boolean).length;
}

//Running the jsperf 100 times and only X were "fair" (had same amount of true as false)
console.log(totals.filter(function(v){return v === 50}).length)
```

Comment: Well, the bigger the sample size the closer to 0.5 it should be, and I assumed those benchmarks use bigger ammounts of tests than 100...

Comment: @JustAPoring you can see the samples right as you benchmark... usually 100 at max